# How do I send a POST request in nodejs with dictionary containing duplicate keys?

Tags: node.js, dictionary, post

I'm trying to do a POST request in nodejs with Restler and this is my code which works and don't have a problem with at all:

```
var post = function (uri, params, callback) {
    var headers = {"User-Agent": user_agent,"Cookie": _sessionCookie}
    rest.post(uri, {
        data: params,
        followRedirects: false,
        headers: headers
    }).on('complete', function (data, response) {
        callback(data, response)
    })
}
```

I did a submit on my browser to see what data i'm suppose to pass which is the image below. But my problem is that i'm required to pass two values for the matchanswers key. 
In my code above the 'params' argument in the post function is a dictionary.
**My question is how do I add two keys(matchanswers) to the 'params' dictionary?**
I've read other posts where they say to do something like:

```
matchanswers:[1,2]
```

but that doesn't work. When I post a dictionary like this it does work:

```
{ qid: '226',
ac: 2,
hash: null,
subject: null,
r1: null,
is_public: 'on',
submit: 1,
answers: '1',
matchanswers: [ 1 ],
importance: '3' }
```

[image]

Comment: What library is `rest.post()` from?  We need to be able to look at what it does and what it supports.

Comment: @jfriend00 its Restler https://github.com/danwrong/restler

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. Node does not support non-unique keys in objects. You can check if rest.post accepts string instead of object and if it does - preconstruct params string.

Comment: I thought of that but it's not working.I used JSON.stringify to convert my dictionary to string and then passed that as the value for 'params' but it didn't work.

Comment: Your dictionary can only contain unique keys so stringifying it won't help. You can construct a string consisting of "key1=value1&key2=value2... " and pass it as params. This string is going to be urlencoded and sent to server as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. When I add 1 matchanswer to the string it works but if I add 2 of them it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

`restler.post()` allows you to send the data in as either a Javascript object or as a string.  If it's a Javascript object, then restler will stringify it for you into JSON.  But, since what you want to send cannot be specified in a Javascript object, you can't send an object in.  Instead, you will have to create your own string that contains the duplicate keys you want.

So, for your `post()` function, let's support this type of structure to generate the Form Data you show in your question:

```
{ 
    qid: '226',
    ac: 2,
    hash: null,
    subject: null,
    r1: null,
    is_public: 'on',
    submit: 1,
    answers: '1',
    matchanswers: [ 2, 3 ],
    importance: '3' 
}
```

If the data in this structure is an array, then we will create dup keys, each with a different value.

We'll create a utility function to encode that into a form data string:

```
function makePostString(obj) {
    var output = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        var base = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=";
        var value = obj[key];
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            value.forEach(function(item) {
                output.push(base + encodeURIComponent(item));
            });
        } else {
            if (value === null || value === undefined) {
                value = "";
            }
            output.push(base + encodeURIComponent(value));
        }
    });
    return output.join("&");
}
```

Now, you can use that in your `post()` function like this:

```
var post = function (uri, params, callback) {
    var headers = {"User-Agent": user_agent,"Cookie": _sessionCookie}
    rest.post(uri, {
        data: makePostString(params),
        followRedirects: false,
        headers: headers
    }).on('complete', function (data, response) {
        callback(data, response)
    })
}
```

And, you pass this type of data as the params:

```
{ 
    qid: '226',
    ac: 2,
    hash: null,
    subject: null,
    r1: null,
    is_public: 'on',
    submit: 1,
    answers: '1',
    matchanswers: [ 2, 3 ],
    importance: '3' 
}
```

Working demo of `makePostString()` here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Lurvxo2e/

Comment: so I modified my code to what you said and it makes sense. But it still doesn't work. When matchanswers is matchanswer:[1,2] it doesnt work but matchanswer:[1] does using your method.

Comment: @altoids - Since I don't have the ability to run your code, can you show what postData is sent when it's `matchanswer:[1,2]` and what the postData should be?  My code intended to send `matchanswer=1&matchanswer=2` (shown in encoded form).

Comment: This is an example output after I call your makePostString : qid=26841&ac=2&hash=&subject=&r1=&is_public=on&submit=1&answers=1&matchanswers=3&matchanswers=2&importance=3

Comment: @altoids - That's what I was expecting and what I thought we were trying to produce.  That is encoded form data.  In the debugger where you grabbed your screen shot, what do you see what you click on the View Url Encoded view of that data and the View Source view of that data?

Comment: I just added two images at the bottom of my initial question. Everything looks legit.

Comment: @altoids - I don't see the two images.  It doesn't look like the edit worked.

Comment: I think I can't edit more than once without a peer review. http://www.screencast.com/t/GU5bWUDBwx and http://www.screencast.com/t/Oee4o4uFIZea

Comment: I think the issue might be with the ac key, i dont know what that value is so ive left at 2 but changed it to 4 and one of the post worked. So ill keep digging see what I find. Thanks for your help.